# Extend Wi-Fi to second floor

Tags: wire, ethernet, cables, wifi, internet

I live in a building that has 2 floors, a friend living on the ground floor has a broadband connection which he uses by connecting the broadband cable to a WiFi router. New he has agreed to share his broadband with me but I live on the First Floor. I want to know how do I extend the network from the ground floor to the first floor.

I have an idea so far: I'll buy a new WiFi router and connect my router with the one on the ground floor using a RJ45 Ethernet cable and install the new router in my living room on the first floor thereby creating my own Wifi with a different SSID and password. I want to know if this is going to work or not, if not then please suggest me the best and the cheapest way possible.

***Additional Details:***
WiFi routers used by both of us :- **TP Link TL-WR845N.**

Broadband Speed :- **25Mbps** (25 Megabits per second)

Comment: Why doesn't the friend just share his wifi password with you and you pa half the bill?

Comment: @whatsisname The wifi speed goes down to below 150 Kbps if I use his wifi router.

Comment: What whatsisname said.  You may need a **wifi extender** if the signal is week.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Will a wifi extender allow me to have my own personal network thereby protecting both mine and my friends privacy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because networking questions aren't part of the [diy.se] remit.

Comment: @FreeMan Said FreeMan over his home internet connection. ;)-  **I agree BTW**. (*this has been a humorous quip based on assumptions by alaskaman that may or may not be valid*)

Comment: @FreeMan Networking per se is not Home Improvement. On the other hand, network cabling to get between the floors is Home Improvement. Mounting the WiFi access point on a wall or ceiling is Home Improvement. etc.

Comment: WiFi extender May boost your speed on the second floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine, and gives you the advantage, if setup properly, of *mostly* separating the two networks. The key is that (typically) a router will have one "in" port and four "out" ports. Your router should have one of the "out" ports from your friend's router go into the "in" port on your router.

The one catch is that, unless the your friend's router is configured to separate the port going to your router from all the other ports, you may be able to see your friend's devices, though your friend will not be able to see your devices. That can lead to three types of possible problems:

- You could print on your friend's networked printers. Not a big deal, as the first time he will complain and the second time start charging for paper/toner.
- If any of your computers are infected with viruses, your friend's computers would be at risk.
- If your friend's computers have minimal security, you may be able to get to "shared" files.

In addition, no matter how you set up the routers (e.g., even if you have one master router and two slaves, so that you can't possibly see each other's computers), if one of you does some nasty stuff that gets you on an IP black list, both of you will be affected.

Comment: I seem to remember that when i put one router on another router i had to go into the set up menu of the second router and change some settings to tell it that it was  not the primary. Or maybe it was the first router,  i can not remember, but i do remember it required more than just plug and play. The OP can/ **SHOULD** research the two routers in question to learn more.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Correct. To do it right, there are a bunch of settings that need to be done. The specifics vary by router model.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I just discovered something called Access Point mode in a wifi router and it does exactly what I wanted. Can I use a different SSID and password to keep my router protected? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the router. Some will let you have 2 different SSIDs with one sharing with the wired ports (i.e., your friend in this case) and one that is by itself (i.e., only WiFi) which would be your connection in this case. That works great if you *only* need WiFi. If you also want wired then 2 routers is still the way to go.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact So if I get a new router for myself and setup my personal wifi can I use additional RJ45 cables to connect my Laptop, PC and my TV to my personal router's additional ports?

Comment: Exactly. Printer/scanner too.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Thank you so very much.